# Levi-Civita property on non-Euclidean space

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

I saw there are similar questions but it seems that no one of them gives an answer to my problem.

I want to prove the following equality:
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{(n-p)!p!}\varepsilon_{i_1\ldots i_pi_{p+1}\ldots i_n}\varepsilon_{\lambda_1\ldots \lambda_n}g^{k_1\lambda_1}\ldots g^{k_p\lambda_p}g^{i_{p+1}\lambda_{p+1}}\ldots g^{i_n\lambda_n}=\frac{1}{\det g}\delta_{i_1}^{[k_1}\ldots\delta_{i_p}^{k_p]}
\end{equation}
I think I have some of the ingredients to get to the result but I am struggling in putting them together.

The $\frac{1}{det g}$ part should come because the following holds:
$\varepsilon_{\lambda_1\ldots\lambda_n}g^{1\lambda_1}\ldots g^{n \lambda_n}=\frac{1}{det g}$ since $g$ with the upper index is the inverse of $g$ with the lower ones.

Moreover, intuitively, the saturation of the indices $i_{p+1}\ldots i_{n}$ brings an $(n-p)!$ factor but I'm also having difficulties in obtaining that rigorously.

Remark on notation and definitions: $\varepsilon$ is the [Levi-Civita symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol), $g$ is a constant metric, the $[ ]$ on the $\delta$ means anti-symmetrization of the indices and the Einstein convention on summations is assumed.

So does anyone have any suggestion on how to get to the result?

Comment: I might suggesting using a letter other than $j$ for the first batch of upper indices---because of the typesetting it is easily confused here with $i$.

Comment: Please define your notation

Comment: @Travis Changed with $k$ thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @Gustavo I edited the question to add informations on the notation. Hope it helps